# Real-time weather for ArcGIS online

Tags: data, arcgis-online, weather

Does anyone know of real-time weather (temp and precip) data for the US that I can bring into ArcGIS online as a layer and also download as a csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out these items in AGOL.
http://arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3b5e854a76a1406bbb21eceff9f991fb
http://arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=93524e20141d4d888fd8c33b1d9d28e7

I didn't download them as a CSV but in ArcMap I did export them to a feature class.